# gem install error: "cannot load such file -- zlib"

Tags: 12.10, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install ruby on rails from scratch on Ubuntu 12.10. Getting help from [this post](http://blog.coolaj86.com/articles/installing-ruby-on-ubuntu-12-04.html):

```
echo "[[ -s '${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm' ]] && source '${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm'" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "[[ -s '${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm' ]] && source '${HOME}/.rvm/scripts/rvm'" >> ~/.zshrc

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

# Then run this in order to make rvm work:
source /home/adige/.rvm/scripts/rvm

# And installed zlib, before ruby:
rvm pkg install zlib

# Last step, installed ruby:
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-zlib-dir=/home/adige/.rvm/usr
```

But the problem is when i try to install gems i get this error:

```
adige@adige-LG:~$ gem install rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

I already have these:

```
curl zlib1g-dev zlib1g libssl-dev build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config
```

So what may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of anyone's interested, i removed `RVM`and compiled `Ruby` from source code, [as the official page recommends](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/), then installed rails gem by:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Using sudo is essential.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and running the following helped me:

```
rvm pkg install zlib
```

and

```
rvm use --default <your_ruby_version>
```

Also make sure that your terminal is set to run as a login shell by going to:

**edit->profile preferences->title and command**

and ticking the 'run command as login shell' box.